# Input placeholder

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать, чтобы при вводе в инпут не скрывался placeholder?

```css
input,select,textarea{
 border-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid #DCECF4;
 color: #81819F;
 font-family: 'Rubik';
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
input,select{
 height: 40px;
}
input.field::placeholder {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #81819F;
  transition: 0.3s;
  opacity: 1;
}
input.field:focus::placeholder {
  transform: translateY(-18px);
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="field" name="email" value=""  placeholder="Email">
<input type="text" class="field" name="password" value="" placeholder="Пароль">
```

Comment: там не placeholder используется...гляньту [тут](https://migo.com.ua/blog/css/google-material-design-input-boxes-in-css3.html) похожий пример

Answer (score 2):

Там `placeholder` зашифрован - в идеале это может быть обычный span как в моём примере

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

div span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

input:focus~span {
  transform: translateY(-18px);
  font-size: 14px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <span>слово</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
  let target = event.target;

  if (target.tagName == 'INPUT' && target.classList.contains('input')) {
    if (target.value.length > 0) {
      target.classList.add('filled');
    } else {
      target.classList.remove('filled');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 30px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 48px;
  cursor: text;
}

.label input {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 0 0 35px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(185, 42, 36);
  color: rgb(185, 42, 36);
}

.label input:focus,
.label input.filled {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #aaaaaa;
  border: 2px solid @mainColor;
  outline: none;
}

.label input:focus+label,
.label input.filled+label {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-34px);
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #8f0222;
}

.label input+label {
  color: #8f0222;
  line-height: 48px;
  padding-left: 3px;
  transform: translateY(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.mail {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
}
```

```html
<form action="POST">
  <div class="start">
    <label class="label mail" for="emailEnter">
        <input class="input" type="email" id="emailEnter" required="required"/>
        <label for="emailEnter">E-mail</label>
    </label>
    <label class="label" for="passwordEnter">
        <input class="input" type="password" id="passwordEnter" minlength="5" required="required"/>
        <label for="passwordEnter">Пароль</label>
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Пример с моего сайта

Comment: А зачем `keyup` со всего документа слушать? Не практичнее было бы, что то на подобии `focus` и `blur`? Или тут затея: поменьше кода?) Да и тега JavaScript почему-то не наблюдается в вопросе.

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, JS здесь не обязателен. Как дополнение. А насчёт `blur` вы правы, так лучше. Просто я с ним не сталкивался ))